# Making strong fence posts in difficult terrain

Tags: fence, root

I am trying to set fence posts, along some stairs (the stonewall in the picture). The bedrock is about 50cm under. The fence will be 2.5m high, therefor it needs a strong base. I don't think the shown stonewall, on its own, is strong enough to hold the fence. The stone at the height of the ruler is under the slab, so it should offer more stability than the others above him, who form a thin (~25cm) wall.

My current plan is to drill holes in the bedrock, attach rebar with injection mortar and then encase the base of the shown 60x60mm angle iron and the rebar in an concrete cast. For additional stability I would attach the angle iron to the mentioned stone, with two glued 12mm rods.

Would that be strong enough to hold the fence?
Do I have better alternatives? (Damaging the stairs isn't an option, albeit drilling is fair use)

[image]

I noticed that there is large root between stonewall and bedrock (red marking). What can I do to prevent the root from damaging the fence post base in the future? Killing the tree (property of my neighbor) isn't an option.

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you, but I'd like to mention that angle iron has poor bending strength compared with other steel sections of equal weight and cost. When subjected to stress over an unsupported span, it twists to relieve stress, then bends. I'd rather see you use an I, H, U or square section if you need a flat face, or round if you don't.